# Login function only works once

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following php functions that process a user logging in. The functions are part of a class User.

```
/*
 * detail() function to get a detail from a database
 * exists() function to check if something exists in a database
 */

private function generate($password, $username = null) {
    if(is_null($username)) {
        $date = '0000-00-00';
    } else {
        $date = $this->_db->detail('last_active', 'users', 'username', $username);
    }

    // This is not the real thing but it will do as an example
    $salt = md5(strrev($password.$date));
    $password = md5($salt.$password.$date).strrev($password);

    return $password;
}

public function login($data = array()) {
    // Check if the user exists
    $username = $data['username'];
    if($this->_db->exists('username', 'users', 'username', $username)) {
        $password = $this->generate($data['password'], $username);

        // If the account is active
        if ($this->_db->detail('active', 'users', 'username', $username) === 1) {
            $stmt = $this->_db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ? AND `active` = 1");
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            if($stmt->num_rows >= 1) {
                // Function to update last_active
                if($this->updateLastActive($username)) {
                    // Function to update password
                    if($this->updatePassword($username, $this->generate($password, $username))) {
                        // Set the session
                        $this->_session->set('user', $this->_db->detail('id', 'users', 'username', $username));

                        if($this->_session->exists('user')) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            echo 'Logging in went wrong';
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo 'Editing the password went wrong';
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Editing last active date went wrong';
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Wrong username and password combination';
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Account not active';
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Username doesn\'t exists';
        return false;
    }
}

private function updateLastActive($username) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    $stmt = $this->_db->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `last_active` = ? WHERE `username` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $date, $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->affected_rows >= 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private function updatePassword($username, $password) {
    $stmt = $this->_db->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = ? WHERE `username` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $password, $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->affected_rows >= 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The user can login with no problem when he just registered. But when the user is logged out and than tries to login again it will fail. The part I get an error on is the following:

```
$stmt = $this->_db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ? AND `active` = 1");
```

I tried to find out where the script fails with `echo` on different places in the functions but I couldn't find the error. The reason why the `generate()` function has `$username = null` is because the same function is used for registration.

So all functions are working but they only work once so this leaves me that someting in the `generate()` function is wrong. I always get the message that there is something wrong with the username / password combination

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very happy.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
The `detail()` and `exists()` functions are part of a class Database.

```
public function detail($detail, $table, $column, $value) {
        if(is_array($detail)) {
            $data = array();

            foreach($detail as $key) {
                $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `$key` FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = ?");
                if(is_numeric($value)) {
                    $stmt->bind_param('i', $value);
                } else {
                    $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
                }
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($detail);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $data[] = $detail;
                $stmt = null;
            }

            return $data;
        } else {
            $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `$detail` FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = ?");

            if(is_numeric($value)) {
               $stmt->bind_param('i', $value);
            } else {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
            }
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($detail);
            $stmt->fetch();

            return $detail;
        }
    }

    public function exists($detail, $table, $column, $value) {
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `$detail` FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = ?");
        switch(is_numeric($value)) {
            case true:
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $value);
                break;
            case false:
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
                break;
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if($stmt->num_rows >= 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You say you got an error, could you post the error message please?

Comment: @lxg well the error messages are above the return false. If I had a PHP error message I would probably already solved it.

Comment: @SuperDJ so your solution is to get the error to show

Comment: @meda if you say it like that you I guess you mean I should force PHP to show me an error message with: `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');`

Comment: I agree with @SuperDJ. Also, are you sure that `$data` is not empty/null? I didn't see the context in which `login()` is called.

Comment: @meda I tried that but it doesn't give me anything

Comment: @だらんぎんじょん I know `$data` is not empty because It does work once like I said. The second time the script is run it will give the message that the username and password combination is wrong. So it already passed one check

Comment: @SuperDJ can you show the detail function ?

Comment: Can you see if you intentionally make a parse error that an error is actually thrown just to make sure display_errors is working?

Comment: @だらんぎんじょん I tried and it displays every error I make

Comment: @SuperDJ Im going through your code I dont understand how a user logs in if the login function does not take a password parameter. It seems like you keep generating a new password every time ?

Comment: @meda Yes it should generate a new password each time a user logs in. Altough the date only changes each day. So in the database the password only changes each day. The `$data` parameter comes from an validate class / function that stores all user data in an array. The array is then passed to this `login()` function

Comment: You generate too many times, even when you update `if($this->updatePassword($username, $this->generate($password, $username)))` so next time how would it match ?

Comment: @meda When I call that line It should already have updated the `last_active` date. The updated `last_active` date is then used in the `generate()` function. This is where the `detail()` function comes in place. This should then together with the password become the new password

Comment: @meda If you know another way to achieve the same without all the generating please share it. Or if you know something else to improve I'm open for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hash field in your table, make it long enough to avoid length issue.

`md5()` is not acceptable now, you should be using better hash function such as `password_hash()`

**Register:**

```
private function register($username, $password) {
    //safer than md5() anyway
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name (`username`, `hash`) VALUES (?, ?);'
    $stmt = $this->_db->mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $hash);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->affected_rows >= 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Login :**

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    // Check if the user exists
    if($this->_db->exists('username', 'users', 'username', $username)) {
        // If the account is active
        if ($this->_db->detail('active', 'users', 'username', $username) === 1) {
            $sql = 'SELECT `username`, `hash` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `active` = 1';
            $stmt = $this->_db->mysqli->prepare();
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $hash);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            if($stmt->num_rows === 1) {
                if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
                    // Function to update last_active
                    if($this->updateLastActive($username)) {
                        echo 'last active updated, Login successful';
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        echo 'Editing last active date went wrong';
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Wrong username and password combination';
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Account not active';
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Username doesn\'t exists';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can still use custom salt, for example

```
$hash = password_hash($password
                     ,PASSWORD_DEFAULT
                     ,array('salt' =>generate()));//generate() returns the salt
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I think I figgured out the problem. At the start of the `login()` function I say that `$password` is the generated hashed password with the password what the user entered. (I don't really use `md5()` to hash my password.) But when I use the `updatePassword()` function with `$password` it actually is the already hashed password. This is then inserted in the database and there for will only work once.

Comment: yes exactly, that's what I pointed out in my [earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193663/login-function-only-works-once/26194356?noredirect=1#comment41073328_26193663) but great that it is solved, good luck